# strange result in Clone()

Tags: c#

I am learning C# Deep Copy and Shallow Copy. Here after Change in demo_obj1, object value is changed but list is not updated but in demo_obj2 object value is changed and also list value updated. Anyone know what is happening here?
Thanks

Visual studio 2017

.Net framework 4.6

```
public class Demo : ICloneable
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string UID { get; set; }

    public Demo(int nValue)
    {
        Value = nValue;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Print(List<Demo> objList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (Demo objDemo in objList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", objDemo.UID, objDemo.Value);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Demo> objList = new List<Demo>();

        Demo obj1 = new Demo(100);
        obj1.UID = "Demo_obj1";

        Demo obj2 = (Demo)obj1.Clone();
        obj2.UID = "Demo_obj2";

        objList.Add(obj1);
        objList.Add(obj2);

        Print(objList);

        obj1 = obj2;
        obj1.Value = 200;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(obj1.UID + " = " + obj1.Value);  
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.UID + " = " + obj2.Value); 

        Print(objList);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Demo_obj1 = 100
Demo_obj2 = 100

Demo_obj2 = 200
Demo_obj2 = 200

Demo_obj1 = 100
Demo_obj2 = 200
```

Comment: @VladimirArustamian he uses MemberwiseClone in his code already

Comment: A more descriptive title would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with cloning, it is references issue.

You have created two objects `obj1` and `obj2` and put them into a list.
Now, you iterate through collection, output it and get expected results.

References are the following now:

```
obj1, list[0] -> Demo_obj1 (100) 
obj2, list[1] -> Demo_obj2 (100) 

Output list[0] => Demo_obj1 (100)
Output list[1] => Demo_obj2 (100)
```

Later, by `obj1 = obj2`, you have assigned a reference of `obj2` to `obj1`. You aren't changing its value or copying your object, you just copy the reference and make it point to another object.
So, actually, both of them now point to the same object.
List contains the same two references to different objects.

```
list[0]             -> Demo_obj1 (100)
obj1, obj2, list[1] -> Demo_obj2 (100)
```

Then you make `obj2.Value = 200` actually changing its value to 200:

```
list[0]             -> Demo_obj1 (100) 
obj1, obj2, list[1] -> Demo_obj2 (200)
```

When you try to output `obj1` and `obj2` UIDs and values now, you will actually output the value of the same object (Demo_obj2).

```
Output obj1 => Demo_obj2 (200)
Output obj2 => Demo_obj2 (200)
```

However, if you try to iterate through collection, you will get `Demo_obj1` and `Demo_obj2` again, according to references table.

```
Output list[0] => Demo_obj1 (100)
Ouptut list[1] => Demo_obj2 (200)
```

Answer (score 4):

So I think there are a couple of points that you need to understand from this question.

Firstly regarding your actual question, the `clone()` method does indeed give you 2 objects. They both start off with the value `100` and are added to a list. Note that this list points to the objects contained within `obj1` and `obj2` and doesn't use the references that you've already created.

Then you do this:

```
obj1 = obj2;
obj1.Value = 200;
```

What this does is updates you're reference `obj1` to `obj2` so now they both point to the same object. You can see this when you do you're logging and you see `200` twice. Note that you have **not** updated the pointers within your list, they are completely different pointers.

Finally when you run your second log, using the pointers within the list you see the original `obj1` with value `100` and the second `obj2` which you updated to have a value of `200`.

---

Now the interesting thing here, is this isn't actually a very good example of a deep clone, because you're using primitive values that'll just get copied anyway. To achieve a better result you probably want to wrap some values within an object:

```
class Bar
{
    public int Value;
    public Bar(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}    

class Foo : ICloneable
{
    public String Id;
    public Bar MyBar;

    public Foo(int value) {
        this.MyBar = new Bar(value);
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Now if you were to construct a bar and do a shallow clone of a `Foo` now, it'd still use the same `Bar`. So:

```
Foo f = new Foo(100);
Foo f2 = (Foo)f.Clone();

f2.MyBar.Value = 200;

Console.WriteLine(f.MyBar.Value); // 200
Console.WriteLine(f2.MyBar.Value); // 200
```

This is where you'd need to get into Deep cloning so that each of the `Foo` instances use a different reference to a unique `Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the variable `obj1` to be the instance held in `obj2`. The original value of `obj1` still exists in the list. on the line where you do `obj1 = obj2;` this is setting the variable `obj1` to hold `obj2`. it does not replace the values of the instance that was previously stored in `obj1`. this is why you are seeing the outputs you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about `MemberwiseClone`, its a red herring here.

Your issue is here:

```
obj1 = obj2;
obj1.Value = 200;
```

1. Variables are placeholders for *values*.
2. The value stored in a reference typed variable is the "address" where the object its referencing "lives" in memory.
3. Variables, by default, are copied by value in C#.

So, this means that `obj1 = obj2; obj1.Value = 200;` does the following:

1. Get the value stored in `obj2` (the address where the instance `{ "Demo_obj2"; 100 }` lives.
2. Copy that value into de variable `obj1`. Now `obj1`'s value is the address where the same instance `{ "Demo_obj2"; 100 }` lives; both `obj1` and `obj2` *point to the same object*.
3. Change the `Value` of the object referenced by `obj1` (or `obj2`) to `200`: the result is the instance `{ "Demo_obj2"; 200 }`.
4. The instance `{ "Demo_obj1"; 100 }` previously referenced by `obj1` is not referenced anymore by any of your two variables `obj1` or `obj2`, but the instance is still stored (*you haven't touched it!*) in the list and reachable through `objList[0]`.

Do you understand now why you are getting the behavior you are seeing?